# Unity Transport Failing on Mac M1 OS Ventura 13.0.1

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, macos-ventura

After updating Mac OS to Ventura 13.0.1 today, my Unity project has started failing on the transport layer. Project continues to work on another Mac that has not received the update yet.

Logs:

```
Server is shutting down due to network transport start failure of UnityTransport!
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Unity.Netcode.NetworkManager:StartHost () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.netcode.gameobjects@1.0.2/Runtime/Core/NetworkManager.cs:1104)
NetworkManagerUI/<LaunchHost>d__7:MoveNext () (at Assets/Main Project/Networking/Scripts/UI/NetworkManagerUI.cs:37)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:SetResult ()
NetworkManagerUI/<Authenticate>d__9:MoveNext () (at Assets/Main Project/Networking/Scripts/UI/NetworkManagerUI.cs:56)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<string>:SetResult (string)
NetworkAuthenticationService/<Authenticate>d__3:MoveNext () (at Assets/Main Project/Networking/Scripts/NetworkRelay.cs:93)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder:SetResult ()
Unity.Services.Authentication.AuthenticationServiceInternal/<HandleSignInRequestAsync>d__101:MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.authentication@2.1.1/Runtime/AuthenticationServiceInternal.cs:465)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1<Unity.Services.Authentication.SignInResponse>:SetResult (Unity.Services.Authentication.SignInResponse)
Unity.Services.Authentication.WebRequest/<SendAsync>d__14`1<Unity.Services.Authentication.SignInResponse>:MoveNext () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.authentication@2.1.1/Runtime/Network/WebRequest.cs:65)
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<string>:SetResult (string)
Unity.Services.Authentication.WebRequest:RequestCompleted (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1<string>,long,bool,bool,string,string,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<string, string>) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.authentication@2.1.1/Runtime/Network/WebRequest.cs:197)
Unity.Services.Authentication.WebRequest/<>c__DisplayClass15_1:<SendAttemptAsync>b__0 (UnityEngine.AsyncOperation) (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.authentication@2.1.1/Runtime/Network/WebRequest.cs:75)
UnityEngine.AsyncOperation:InvokeCompletionEvent () (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/AsyncOperation.cs:21)
```

There was not much on Google when searching for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the OS update caused one system or non system app to switch its PORT to `7777` which is the one I was using for my project. It was a simple problem with taken PORT, changing this to `7778` or any free PORT fixed the problem.